# Issues with presenting collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to present a view controller when a user taps a button.
However I get the error message:

`UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter`

However I'm sure I set my layout in my viewDidLoad...

Any suggestions?

Here's the code.

**Here's where I present the view controller**

```
func handleLogout(){

    print("logout")

    let loginController = LoginController()

    present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

**Here's login controller viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()

    collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

If anything, I think I might have to initialize it before I present it. Not too sure how to do that.

Comment: how did you initiate your `collectionView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was right in suspecting that the collectionview had to be initialized **before** presenting.

That's done like this

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let loginController = LoginController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)
    //
    return CGSizeMake(cellSize)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

It say you need to use `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:` to initiate your `collectionView` programmatically